# Getting field content from parent node (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-nodes

At the moment admin can upload background image from the admin to the each page. So basically page node type has a field called background_image and then I get that image place it to div's background image with CSS.

I also have second content type called car_article. These pages are listed under one of those pages nodes. So basically sitemap looks like this:

```
Cars (node type = page, parent)
-Audi (node type = car_article, child page)
-BMW (node type = car_article, child page)
-Chevrolet (node type = car_article, child page)
```

Now what I would need to do is get the background image from the parent page, Cars page in this case. So how can I get field content from parent page. And this would need to work always if page is car_article node type, it would automatically try to load background image from parent page.

Thanks!

Comment: No one knows how to achieve this?

Comment: I am not clear as to what you are trying to do. Pls provide links and code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve that by using http://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views.

But it's perhaps overkill...

With http://drupal.org/project/menu_node you can know witch nid the parent menu is pointing on.

For two levels is not very a problem to run on more node_load. What is going to be hard is if you want make it recursive and avoiding loading every node until you find one with an image..

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but you could try get access to the top node using arg()

e.g. if your page is
**/cars/bmw**
and the nodes are structured
**/node/care_node/bmw_node**

you can use `arg(1)` to get the id of the car node and then load that into a variable

e.g.

```
$parentNode = node_load(arg(1));
```

Now you can use `parentNode` to access the node of the parent.

If your site is more complex and you have many levels you could do some math to find the current arg and then -1

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar problem and here is how I get to the field, but I think it's rather convoluted.

```
$menuParent = menu_get_active_trail();
reset($menuParent); //point to first
next($menuParent);  //jump next, to skip 'home'
$firstItem = current($menuParent);
$path = drupal_get_normal_path($firstItem['link_path']);
$node = menu_get_object('node', 1, $path);
$field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'background_image');
$sectionBgUrl = file_create_url($field[0]['#item']['uri']);
```